# Can one use .validate directives to synchronize schema in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

In the Firebase security rules file, could one effectively use the '.validate' directives to synchronize schema, that is, make sure when one part of the Firebase is modified, another part gets updated as well? Or is this a bad/invalid idea?

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a Todo list app. I want to be able to create tasks in my todo list with specified tags. For each tag in the app, there should be a respective tag child field in the "tags" field in my Firebase backend. The tag field should contain an ordered list of references to tasks in the "tasks" field. So, if a task is created with "#foo" tag, then it's name (id) should be referenced in "tasks/foo". Also, whenever a task is removed, it's reference in each tag should be removed, and when a tag in has no children it should be removed.

To clarify here's an example of the schema:

```
{
    "tasks": {
        "-sdjfaowneono": {
            "headline": "Get some milk",
            "completed": false,
            "tags": {
                "0": "all",
                "1": "shopping"
            }
        },
        "-asdfhsadfsafwirn": {
            "headline": "Pick up the kids",
            "completed": false,
            "tags": {
                "0": "all"
            }
        }
    },
    "tags": {
        "all": {
            "0": "-sdjfaowneono",
            "1": "-asdfhsadfsafwirn"
        },
        "shopping": {
            "0": "-sdjfaowneono"
        }
    }
}
```

Again, if task "-sdjfaowneono" was removed, so would the "shopping" tag be removed.

In conclusion, I need to synchronize the "tags" schema with the "tasks" schema in a specific way. Should I do this synchronization in the Security Rules? Or should I do this at the app level? And if I do it at the app level, there is a risk that the app bugs out and doesn't add/remove a tag which it should, so how do I overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

To use this with security rules, you will need to change one or the other to use the tag id as the key, rather than an array value, since there is no way to specify a wild card or search multiple children to see if one contains the correct value.

So if you changed your "tags" path to look like this:

```
"tags": {
   "all": {
      "-sdjfaowneono": true,
      "-asdfhsadfsafwirn": true
   },
   "shopping": {
       "-sdjfaowneono": true
   }
}
```

Then you could validate like this:

```
"tasks": {
   "$task": {
      "tags": {
         "$tag": {
             ".validate": "root.child('tags/'+newData.val()+'/'+$task).exists()"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This uncovers a basic design practice that I've discovered while building with Firebase: I tend to prefer keys to values for storing any sort of foreign key reference.

Also, keep in mind that this only enforces that they match up on write. It does help with deletions since .validate will only run if the value exists.

You could enforce the same behavior on deletions by appending this to the write rule:

```
".write": " ... && (newData.exists() || !root.child('tags/'+newData.val()+'/'+$task).exists())"
```